# JAVA Regular expression to extract string after special characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract string after the first three dots (example yyyy in following pattern):`xxx.xxx.xxxx.yyyy`
here x could be anything (no,letters or *)
yyyy can be letter or nos or abc. or abc*

On using java pattern "`^.*\\.([^.]+)$`" , it works fine for string ab.bc.de.ef :
Code:

```
static final String REC_PATTERN = "^.*\\.([^.]+)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REC_PATTERN);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("ab.bc.de.ef");
System.out.println(m.group(1)) //out put ef.
```

but it fails for `ab.bc.cd.de.11111` , I require output as de.1111 instead of 1111.
Could someone please help with relevant regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this pattern : `^(?:\w+\.){3}(.*)$`, as `String` : `"^(?:\\w+\\.){3}(.*)$"`

It finds the 3 dots with its text before, and capture what is next

And you may have forget `m.find()`, without that it doe not work

---

- [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/)
- [`Online Demo`](https://ideone.com/8htzSK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^(?:[^.]*\\.){3}", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oeK0QV/1)

Here `^(?:[^.]*\\.){3}` will match 3 part that are followed by dot at the start of string and when we replace it by `""` it leaves the part you want in output.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava , I can not use the above code as i require regular expression to solve it due to relevant code being available in library.

Comment: What have posted above is 100% regex based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a regular expression? Because this problem looks like it could be solved by a simple String.split():

```
String text = "ab.bc.de.ef.1234";
String match = text.split(".")[4];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `text.split("\\.", 4)[3];`? The `String.split()` function takes a regex as first parameter and OP wants the fourth result, not the second. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Yes, I fixed it... But it does not need to be a regex, for me it works with "." aswell

Comment: @Piwo, yes it needs to be solved using regex as the above code to split the id is in third party library. Only change i can do is supply the reg-ex.

Comment: @Piwo It doesn't work for me, I just tried it. Are you sure you are using Java? `System.out.print(Arrays.toString("foo.bar.baz".split("\\.")));` prints `[foo, bar, baz]` for me. Using `"."` instead of `"\\."` prints `[]`.

Comment: TIO to prove it: https://tio.run/##pYw7DsIwEETr5BSWK7tgL5CKA1ClJBSbD5GDY1veTaSAcnZjFDgBxWikeaM34YonHwY39Y9k5uAjiylvsLCxcI4RN6pSWFprOtFZJBIXNE68yuI7EiPnWr3pxZyRqjkaN15vAuNI@vMs6o14mMEvDCFDtk4damB/3JW8ew8txpynBArWsJJNA1JrXf2h@An2ck/pDQ